# How do you translate comments_number function text in a theme?

Tags: translation

If I'm just echoing regular text, I do this:

```
<?php _e('This post is closed to new comments.','my-theme') ?>
```

But how would I translate the text in `comments_number();` so that the "Comments" text can be translated? Like this:

```
<?php comments_number( 'Comments (0)', 'Comments (1)', 'Comments (%)' ); ?>
```

Comment: `comments_number( __('Comments (0)'), __('Comments (1)'), __('Comments (%)') ); See [Theme internationalization](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/).

Comment: Thanks @MaxYudin that works. You should post that as an answer to get credit :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to make these strings translatable by using `__()` function:

```
comments_number( __('Comments (0)'), __('Comments (1)'), __('Comments (%)') );
```

If you want to use the custom `textdomain`, e.g. `'test'`:

```
comments_number( __('Comments (0)', 'test'), __('Comments (1)', 'test'), __('Comments (%)', 'test') );
```

For more information see:

- [__()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2)
- [Theme internationalization](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/)
- Very good article by Samuel Wood a.k.a. Otto: [Internationalization: You’re probably doing it wrong](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/).

Answer (score -1):

The `comments_number` function is calling `get_comments_number_text` function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments_number_text/

In that function there are your strings to translate

```
function get_comments_number_text( $zero = false, $one = false, $more = false ) {
    $number = get_comments_number();

    if ( $number > 1 ) {
        if ( false === $more ) {
            /* translators: %s: number of comments */
            $output = sprintf( _n( '%s Comment', '%s Comments', $number ), number_format_i18n( $number ) );
        } else {
            // % Comments
            $output = str_replace( '%', number_format_i18n( $number ), $more );
        }
    } elseif ( $number == 0 ) {
        $output = ( false === $zero ) ? __( 'No Comments' ) : $zero;
    } else { // must be one
        $output = ( false === $one ) ? __( '1 Comment' ) : $one;
    }
    /**
     * Filter the comments count for display.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     *
     * @see _n()
     *
     * @param string $output A translatable string formatted based on whether the count
     *                       is equal to 0, 1, or 1+.
     * @param int    $number The number of post comments.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'comments_number', $output, $number );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers my question...

Comment: Sorry, I misreaded your question and was actually answering something else... The comment of Max Yudin gives you correct answer...